# Как корректно переписать данные в тот же файл

Tags: c#, файлы, потоки-данных, .net-core

Есть файл, и мне нужно переписать данные в тот же файл, т. е. как-то так:

<sub>До</sub>

```
┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ 01 │ 23 │ 45 │ 67 │ 89 │ ab │ cd │ ef │  
└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

<sub>После</sub>

```
┌────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ 01 │ 23 │ 45 │ 67 │ 89 │ 67 │ 89 │ ef │
└────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┴────┘
               ╘═════════╧═════════╛
                    │         ↑
                    └─────────┘
                    Copy/Paste
```

При этом можно использовать буфера только ограниченного размера (например, 1024 байт).

---

Пока есть только такой способ:

<sub>Псевдокод</sub>

```
void Copy(Stream stream, Range from, Index to)
{
    // checks skipped

    var (fromOff, len) = from.GetOffsetAndLength(stream.Length);
    var toOff = to.GetOffset(stream.Length);

    var oldPos = stream.Position;
    Span<byte> buf = stackalloc byte[1024];
    var off = 0;

    // var otd = toOff - fromOff; // From & To offsets Delta
    // stream.Seek(fromOff, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    while (true)
    {
        stream.Seek(fromOff + off, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // or remove
        var bufLen = stream.ReadBlock(buf);

        var bufLenToCopy = Math.Min(bufLen, len - off); // или `bufLenForCopy`?

        stream.Seek(toOff + off, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // or stream.Seek(otd, SeekOrigin.Current);
        stream.Write(buf[..bufLenToCopy]); 
        // stream.Seek(bufLenToCopy - otd, SeekOrigin.Current);

        off += bufLenToCopy;

        if (off >= len) break;
        // т. к. увеличение `off` равно 0, зн. условие выхода из цикла никогда не выполниться
        if (bufLen == 0) { /*throw*/ }
    }

    stream.Position = oldPos;
}
```

Можно ли его [способ] как-нибудь улучшить? Или это уже реализовано в .NET и я занимаюсь изобретением велосипедов?

Comment: Здесь только не хватает всяких проверок типа `CanSeek`, `CanWrite`, и т.д. Код вполне вменяемый, не считая закомментированных его частей, затрудняющих чтение.

Comment: @aepot надо внимательнее читать комментарии :) я же написал: "checks skipped" – проверки пропущены (типо я не знаю что нужно проверять :) ). комменты да, нужно убрать, только всегда найдётся тот, кто скажет, что ничего не понятно, ведь `stackalloc` уже low-level что надо цякаць з гораду

Comment: Если вы не двигаете данные, а пишете просто поверх, то выглядит норм.

Comment: @tym32167 там же написано: метод `Copy`, ни слова про `Move`

Comment: Ну хорошо, это как то противоречит моим словам?

Comment: Для стримов ничего стандартного нет. Для массивов есть [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy).

Comment: Можно сделать `Span.Slice` на последней итерации - это позволит избежать копирования лишних байтов. Но это микрооптимизация.

Comment: Приходит в голову Memory-Mapped File. Это может в некоторых случаях оказаться удобным. Но в то же время избыточным.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov там же есть слайсинг...

Comment: Я вот [так](https://pastebin.com/RpXn1fWq) написал. Но да, это то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

Да, ваш способ написан добротно и в улучшениях ядра алгоритма не нуждается.

Изменения в финальной версии:

- Убрать лишние комментарии
- Вместо `// checks skipped` написать чеки аргументов метода
- Вместо `/*throw*/` (строка 32) написать выбрасывание исключений